# PayPal Refund DoReferenceTransaction

Tags: paypal

I thought I read somewhere that you don't refund a DoReferenceTransaction and just refund the transaction that was referenced.  I could of swore it worked but now it just does not.

Does PayPal have a feature where you can refund all reference transactions by refunding the parent or do I need to individually refund each reference transaction?

If the latter is true is there a way to refund multiple transactions without multiple calls to PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Each transaction is an individual transaction and would need to be refunded using the RefundTransaction API one-at-a-time.